# Differences in Performance Between in MASS Package lm.ridge() and enet in elasticnet Package

Tags: r, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

A background:

I am currently working with the 'elasticnet' package ([elasticnet v.1.3)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/elasticnet/versions/1.3) maintained by Hui Zou. This package was developed to accompany Hui Zou and Trevor Hastie's Statistical Society B article  ["Regularization and variable selection via the elastic net"](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf) in which they propose the elastic net method, a method that weights and counterweights the $L_1$ and $L_2$ norms via a selection of a particular parameter $\lambda$ defined as the "quadratic penalty parameter" in the package documentation. When $\lambda = 0$, the `enet` algorithm effectively performs the LASSO fit and when $\lambda = 1$ *I think* the algorithm performs a Ridge Regression fit.

This is where my question/confusion begins:

I am comparing this `enet` method of variable selection to `lars` LASSO and `MASS lm.ridge()` methods by changing values of the quadratic penalty parameter $\lambda$. I have confirmed that when $\lambda = 0$ I get the LASSO fit as expected. However, when I take $\lambda = 1$ I get `enet` results that are wildly different from the `lm.ridge` results, and much more inaccurate. As a side note, I am always using `predict(..., naive = FALSE, ...)` when performing my calculations. A snippet of my code is below:

```
# Elastic Net with Parameter 1
  lm_EN3 <- enet(x = data.matrix(curr_train_BH0[,2:17]), y = curr_train_BH0$Y,
                 lambda = 1.0)
  step_index = as.numeric(names(which.min(lm_EN3$Cp)))
  EN3_pred = predict(lm_EN3, newx = data.matrix(curr_test_BH0[,2:17]),
                     s = step_index, type = 'fit', mode = 'step')$fit
  EN3_pred_MSE <- MSE(EN3_pred, curr_test_BH0$Y)
  pred_MSE_vec <- append(pred_MSE_vec, EN3_pred_MSE)
  #print("EN3 Success!")
  
  
  
  
  
  
  # Ridge regression model with 16 predictors and select best lambda
  myLambda = seq(0.0001,10.0,0.00001)
  lm_Ridge <- lm.ridge(Y~., data = curr_train_BH0, lambda = myLambda)
  index = which.min(lm_Ridge$GCV)
  bestLambda2 <- myLambda[index]
  lm_Ridge_best <- lm.ridge(Y~., curr_train_BH0, lambda = bestLambda2)
  predicted <- cbind(1,as.matrix(curr_test_BH0[,2:17]))%*%coef(lm_Ridge_best)
  Ridge_pred_MSE <- MSE(predicted, curr_test_BH0$Y)
  pred_MSE_vec <- append(pred_MSE_vec, Ridge_pred_MSE)
  #print("Ridge Success!")
```

**Question:**

Am I incorrect that thinking $\lambda = 1$ would correspond to a Ridge regression approach in variable selection? If so, what does quadratic penalty parameter of $1$ produce when using `enet` compared to a `lm.ridge()` approach?